# ruby on rails: Rails.cache.write returning false for array of specific object fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached

I'm trying to save a large array of ids and permalinks for approved pages in memcache so that I don't have to hit the database multiple times for the same data.

My code:

```
if Rails.cache.exist?("ids_and_permalinks_array")
  data = Rails.cache.fetch("ids_and_permalinks_array")
else
  data = []

  Page.approved.select('id, permalink').find_each { |f| data << f }

  Rails.cache.write("ids_and_permalinks_array", data, :expires_in => 12.hours)
end
```

`approved` on `Page` is a simple `where(:approved => true)`, and data is a large array of object subsets like `#<Page id: 1, permalink: "page-permalink-1">` (the array is around 50,000 objects).

The `Rails.cache.write` line returns `false` when run from the console, with the development.log showing: `Cache write: ids_and_permalinks_array ({:expires_in=>43200 seconds})`

So, the log says it's writing to the cache, but `Rails.cache.fetch("ids_and_permalinks_array")` returns `nil`.

Suggestions?  Anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I've also tried this, and still don't get the value written to cache:

```
Rails.cache.fetch("ids_and_permalinks_array", :expires_in => 12.hours, :race_condition_ttl => 10.minutes) do
  Page.approved.select('id, permalink').find_each { |p| data << p }
end
```

** UPDATE 2 **

I added `Rails.logger.info("\n#{Rails.cache.exist?("ids_and_permalinks_array")\n")` to the beginning and end of the method call this code is in.  Each time, at the beginning of the method call, it logs `false` and at the end it logs `true`...  So, it's working, but is it only setting for that thread / instance of the method call?

Comment: Are you running in development or production mode?  Caching is turned off by default in development mode

Comment: In the line starting "So, the log says it's writing to the cache", did you mean to say `Rails.cache.fetch("page-permalink-1")`?... because that key doesn't match the one you're writing to.

Comment: @rossta - yes, corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a `Rails.cache.fetch`, the given block needs to return the expected value. In:

```
Rails.cache.fetch("ids_and_permalinks_array", :expires_in => 12.hours, :race_condition_ttl => 10.minutes) do
  Page.approved.select('id, permalink').find_each { |p| data << p }
end
```

the result of the block is `nil`, because that is the return value of `find_each`.

Try something like this instead:

```
Rails.cache.fetch("ids_and_permalinks_array", :expires_in => 12.hours, :race_condition_ttl => 10.minutes) do
  [].tap do |data|
    Page.approved.select('id, permalink').find_each { |p| data << p }
  end
end
```

Using tap will ensure that the resulting array is passed as the return value to the fetch block.

Comment: I copied that code exactly, and added `data = ` in front of the first line, and running `Rails.cache.fetch("ids_and_permalinks_array")` after still returns nil.  Do I need to explicitly set the cache value in the block?  The documentation says I don't, but I'm not convinced...

Comment: Would it have anything to do with the fact that this code is inside a method which is cached using `caches_action`?

Comment: That's possible. Have you tried running this code in isolation, say on the console or in a unit test?